# When do Enum instances get created?

Tags: java, enums

I have a simple question regarding `Enums` in Java Please refer to the following code . When do the instances like `PropName .CONTENTS` get instantiated ?

```
public enum PropName {

  CONTENTS("contents"),
  USE_QUOTES("useQuotes"),
  ONKEYDOWN("onkeydown"),
  BROWSER_ENTIRE_TABLE("browseEntireTable"),
  COLUMN_HEADINGS("columnHeadings"),
  PAGE_SIZE("pageSize"),
  POPUP_TITLE("popupTitle"),
  FILTER_COL("filterCol"),
  SQL_SELECT("sqlSelect"),
  ;

  private String name;

  private PropName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's created when the class is loaded. But why this question ? What's the problem you have ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's created when the class is loaded, just like any static code block.

Answer (score 5):

When the PropName class is loaded by the class loader. Enum constants are static final fields of their class.

Comment: How can we see a class being loaded in a debugger ?

Answer (score 3):

The enum types' instances get created in the **class loader subsystem** in the **last phase of "loading the class file"**, called ***Initialization*** and not at runtime, like other class instances.
They come first, before any other static field/variable initializations and that is why you can't access static fields inside an enum's constructor either, unless they are a constant.